# interoperatability Cpluspluss_CLI_ManagedArray <--> Array

Tags: c++-cli, interop, clr

How can i convert interoperatability between a c++/CLI Array and a native c++ array AND VICE VERSA.

array^ Cpluspluss_CLI_ManagedArray;

unsigned char* UnmanagedArray;

I found the System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal; (IntPtr) there is so much of information for a first timer like me (to CLI) So I'm not sure about which one to use.

Thank you

Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// unmanaged to managed...

IntPtr ptr((unsigned char*)UnmanagedArray);

array< Byte>^Cpluspluss_CLI_ManagedArray = gcnew array(UnmanagedArrayLength);

Marshal::Copy(ptr, Cpluspluss_CLI_ManagedArray, 0, UnmanagedArrayLength);

// unmanaged to managed...
[See this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012396/arraybyte-to-unsigned-char-marshall-class-interop-issue)